# FOSRest bundle not found route for action

Tags: rest, symfony, routes, restful-url, fosrestbundle

I try to use FOSRestBundle but gets error:

```
No route found for "GET /en/users"
```

Here is controller action:

```
public function getUsersAction()
{
    return new Response('resting');
}
```

Here is config in app/config/routin.yml:

```
geekhub_main:
  resource: "@GeekhubMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /{_locale}
  requirements:
    _locale: |uk|en
  defaults: { _locale: en }
```

Here is config in MainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
users:
type:     rest
resource: Geekhub\MainBundle\Controller\UsersController
```

Here is config for the rest:

```
fos_rest:
format_listener: true
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
view:
    view_response_listener: true
    formats:
        json: true
        xml: true
        yml: true
```

Route debug display:

```
 get_users                GET    ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/users.{_format}                     
 get_user                 GET    ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/users/{slug}.{_format}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you not need to include your format? So `/en/users.json`?

Comment: if format dont assigned evidently it will be in .json format by defalut! but your advice  has the right to life :)